# Error when trying to run Rmarkdown - Error: LaTeX failed to compile

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

I'm triying to run Rmarkdow code on windows to creat pfd and reciveing the follow error:

```
! ...וסף\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:941: ...וסף\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:864: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
Running the command C:\Users\���� ����\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\fmtutil-user.exe

Error: LaTeX failed to compile gg.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See gg.log for more info.
In addition: There were 27 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted
```

I trid already to follow the instraction over here [RStudio does not detect TeX installation #103](https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex/issues/103)

```
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)


Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
  LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: Asia/Hebron
tzcode source: internal

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3   bslib_0.4.2       cachem_1.0.7      cli_3.6.1         digest_0.6.31    
  ellipsis_0.3.2    evaluate_0.20     fastmap_1.1.1     fontawesome_0.5.1 fs_1.6.2         
  glue_1.6.2        graphics_4.3.0    grDevices_4.3.0   highr_0.10        htmltools_0.5.5  
  jquerylib_0.1.4   jsonlite_1.8.4    knitr_1.42        lifecycle_1.0.3   magrittr_2.0.3   
  memoise_2.0.1     methods_4.3.0     mime_0.12         R6_2.5.1          rappdirs_0.3.3   
  rlang_1.1.1       rmarkdown_2.21    sass_0.4.5        stats_4.3.0       stringi_1.7.12   
  stringr_1.5.0     tinytex_0.45      tools_4.3.0       utils_4.3.0       vctrs_0.6.2      
  xfun_0.39         yaml_2.3.7       

Pandoc version: 2.19.2
> tinytex::tinytex_root()
[1] "C:\\Users\\עידן יוסף\\AppData\\Roaming\\TinyTeX"
```

Than:

```
> Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "c:\\rtools43\\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\\bin;c:\\rtools43\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.0\\bin\\x64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Razer Chroma SDK\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Razer Chroma SDK\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Razer\\ChromaBroadcast\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Razer\\ChromaBroadcast\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\עידן יוסף\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\עידן יוסף\\AppData\\Roaming\\TinyTeX\\bin\\windows;C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\resources\\app\\bin\\quarto\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\resources\\app\\bin\\postback"
```

This give nothing
`tinytex::tlmgr_path()`

and that:

```
> file.info(p)
                                                                      size isdir mode mtime ctime
C:\\Users\\עידן יוסף\\AppData\\Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe   NA    NA <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
                                                                      atime  exe
C:\\Users\\עידן יוסף\\AppData\\Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe  <NA> <NA>
```

I hope it usful i can check other things but not sure what to do

kndly any advice will be help full

regardss

Answer (score 1):

This issue [has recently been resolved](https://yihui.org/en/2023/11/tinytex-path/) in the R package **tinytex**:

```r
install.packages('tinytex', repos = 'https://rstudio.r-universe.dev')
# remember to restart R after installation
```

Basically you need to either move or reinstall TinyTeX to a location where the path does not contain non-ASCII characters, e.g.,

```r
tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()
```